# How many matches will there be at Euro 2016

Tags: football, euro

I'm writing some software for recording stats about football tournaments and I need to know how many matches will there be at Euro 2016.

Also what is the largest number of matches that are likely to be played simultaneously.

Comment: I vote to close because it is possible to find the answer with a very simple search on the web

Comment: Based on previous attempts to close due to the question being ["easy to look up"](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12722/ball-goes-through-the-strike-zone-but-the-catcher-doesnt-catch-the-ball#comment19370_12722) or ["too basic"](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/if-the-pitcher-throws-to-1st-base-to-try-to-get-the-base-runner-out-is-the-runn?rq=1#comment19667_12860), it was determined that said reasons were not valid reasons to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How many matches will there be at Euro 2016?

According to the [UEFA EURO 2016 website](http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/#md/1), 51.

- Group Stage - MD 1: 12
- Group Stage - MD 2: 12
- Group Stage - MD 3: 12
- Round of 16: 8
- Quarterfinals: 4
- Semi-finals: 2
- Finals: 1

> What is the largest number of matches that are likely to be played simultaneously?

The largest number of matches that *start at the same time* is 2, found in Group Stage - MD 3. Within reason, the largest number of matches that *are likely to be played simultaneously* is 2.

<sub>In the event the earlier scheduled games run longer than three hours (I'm not sure how un/likely that is), then it is possible (if reasonable) that the largest number of matches that are likely to be played simultaneously is 4 (but it would be during the very end of the earlier scheduled games and during the very beginning of the later scheduled games, again, if reasonable).</sub>

Comment: This is wrong because there it will never happen that 4 matches are played simultaneously: the largest number of matches played simultaneously is **2** (the last matches of each of 6 groups)

Comment: @Ale You're correct, I didn't take note of the different days those matches are played. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 3):

A simple search would have shown this [Euro 2016 calendar](http://it.uefa.com/uefaeuro/news/newsid=2317794.html).

- **36** matches for rounds
- **8** round of 16
- **4** quarterfinals
- **2** semifinals
- **1** final

**total 51 matches**

The largest number of matches played simultaneously is **2** (the last matches of each of 6 groups)